# How do you write a multiple condition IF statement with the same output?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I've been working on a file for fun for MONTHS now. It is something that I'm passionate about and I have been making it available to other collectors. It is a tracking sheet for a particular set of baseball cards. I've finished the design and most everything else. I've slowly been automating the file as well to make Revisions for those who have the original (beta).

Basically I have been trying to come up with an IF statement that would search in Column A for example if the grading company is equal to either "PSA" or "SGC". The conflict is that with both grading companies not all grades are unique (though most are) but the ones that are unique I've figured out.

BOTH PSA and SGC can issue a grade of 10 and Authentic. PSA 10 would be top of the line condition. SGC 10 would be the opposite a very low conditioned grade.

I feel like I'm missing something slightly with this code but I'm on the right track:

```
=IF((AND(A1:A6="PSA",A1:A6="SGC")),"B1:B6","B1:B6")
```

[image]

[image]

Alright as you can see there are two grading companies that can be manually input to the front page. The picture above is a separate sheet that I want to connect to the front (main sheet). The new picture you can notice two conflicts both have Authentic (Authentic), Authentic (Trimmed), and 10 for grades.

My IF statement should be simple perhaps I'm making it more difficult than it should be.

Referencing the top photo that would be on the main page. IF Column A equals PSA then display Column B's value in Column C.

IF column A equals SGC then display Column B's value in Column C.

The reason I need it this way is because I could do a simple COUNTIF which I did with the others specifically for column C but then it wouldn't know which grading company the Authentic (Authentic), Authentic (Trimmed), or 10 came from thus throwing my numbers off on the other sheet (Photo 2).

Comment: Can you post a link to your spreadsheet?  
Also, your ""true" and "false" conditions are the same...what do you really need there?

Comment: Also, and maybe you did an I missed it when I was reading, it would be helpful if you show the source data, and then, in english, explain the IF statement. Like how you would determine it if you manually had to do this for each row.

Comment: I've added another photo and in English what I'm trying to do let me know if that clears it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was self-resolved using an alternative solution.

for a PSA that would grade a 10 and conflict with the SGC 10. I just put PSA 10 in the column and for SGC just left it 10.

I did similar inputs for the Authentic grading. 
SGC = "A"
SGC = "A Trimmed"

PSA="Authentic"
PSA="Authentic Trimmed"